# Amazon EC2 doesn't know about CRON jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a Rails app, running on EC2 instance (Ubuntu distribution).

The thing is that the CRON tasks are never ran - which is the problem. They are working locally, but not on Amazon EC2 (probably because of incorrect paths to ruby etc - but unfortunately I am not very skilled in this area). How to run the CRON tasks with the Rails app (RVM)?

I am fighting the third day with this issue, but still cannot make it work, so I would be very grateful for every help.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

> crontab -e

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/user_name/project/releases/201309301$
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user_name/f$

0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user_name/f$


# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/user_name/project/releases/20130930170$
```

> schedule.rb

```
set :output, "/home/user_name/project/current/log/cron_log.log"
every 5.minutes do
  puts "It's working !!!"
  runner "User.grab_first_user!", :environment => 'production'
end
```

> cron_log.log

```
: No such file or directory
....
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory

/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/some_great_command: No such file or directory
```

Comment: So what is in your `crontab` file and why do you think it has wrong path to ruby?

Comment: Could you run `which ruby` in console and what it's output is?

Comment: can you try running the command `/usr/bin/env | grep "PATH"` and inspect if path to your `rvm` is there?  Also try running `which -a ruby` to find all the versions of ruby as they appear in your PATH env

Answer (score 1):

You should use absolute paths in cron. There is an option to define a PATH variable in cron which will be available to all your cron jobs. Look into cron documentation.

You can also use -l options with bash to invoke bash as alogin shell (meaning, make it set the environment based on your .bashrc etc.). See the sample command below

```
"/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /project/folder; RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/bundle exec rails runner ./script/monthly.rb >> ./cron_log 2>&1'"
```

Since you are using `whenever`, have you defined `job_type` in your `schedule.rb` correctly? something like this...

```
job_type :rake, "cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment bundle exec rake :task --silent :output"
job_type :runner,  "cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment bundle exec rails runner :task :output"
```

Also set the output so that all output from cron jobs is captured in a file for you to inspect

```
set :output, "/home/project/log/cron_log.log"
```

You should then be able to define tasks like this

```
every :day, :at => '12:01am' do
  rake "ts:index"
end

every :month, :at => '05:10am' do
  runner 'script/monthly_job.rb'  
end

every :saturday, :at => "2:00am" do
  command "/home/project/scripts/clean_stale_users.sh"
end
```

**Update**:

if using `rvm`, follow these instructions for [rvm integration with cron](http://rvm.io/integration/cron)

Comment: Hi `Eternal-Learner`, yes, I used the absolute paths, tasks should be defined correctly as well... I also added the logs (I updated the OP). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this I found is to use the 'whenever' gem, which allows you to define the task in your application and then if you use capistrano to deploy, it can automatically update the cron tasks on the server.
If not using Capistrano you can use the command line on the server to generate the jobs.

Whenever:
https://github.com/javan/whenever

Using Capistrano with Whenever is also described there.

Comment: I am using the `Whenever` gem, but it just doesn't work on the server - probably because of the incorrect paths to ruby or something.